# How to convert 23 digit float number from string to float and back in python?

Tags: python, precision

In python (3.6.2) I want to convert a string-representation of a number to a float, change it, and convert it back. So something like

```
a = '147211834412830112.000'
b = float(a)
c = b+0.001
print("%23.3f" % c)
147211834412830112.000
```

But with the code above it does not work correctly.

What are the possibilities to do that with python and not to lose precision on such a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve the precision of your number, try using [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html):

```
from decimal import Decimal

a = '147211834412830112.000'
b = Decimal(a)
c = b+Decimal('0.001')
print(c)
```

Result:

```
$ python x.py 
147211834412830112.001
```